# How to set up Apache server via an FTP account

Tags: django, apache, apache2, mod-python

I have developed a web application in Django and would like to go online i have an FTP access to the hosting server I am a beginner to "setting up a website" i would like to know how to install apache on that server and have my application working

Kindly provide detailed info as i am newbie, any links or tutorials would help a lot

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have user level access to the machine (ie: you don't have root), then you won't be able to control what web server runs and you can only control its settings to a limited regard. You will have to consider contacting your provider or looking for a different hosting package if the server doesn't meet you needs.

Typically, if it is a hosting server, the administrators will already have web server software like Apache running. You simply just have to upload what you would like to have displayed (typically to a directory called "public_html" or something like that), and it will display when someone visits your site. Hopefully they support things like Django, otherwise you might need to look at other options.

Your hosting provider is most likely to have specific and the most relevant instructions for how to upload your website.

Comment: Can u help me regarding the Django Application part
and how do i know if my apache has mod_python installed